# Error when copying data into Variant table from AVRO file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, avro

I am completing a snowflake university workshop but I have run into a problem.  The course has provided an AVRO file and asked us to insert the data into a Variant column table.  However when I run the COPY INTO commamd I get this error:

Number of columns in file (11) does not match that of the corresponding table (1), use file format option error_on_column_count_mismatch=false to ignore this error File 'iot_files/iot_files_sample_output.avro', line 1, character 827 Row 1, column "IOT_AVRO_DATA"[11] If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.

These are the instructions given by the course:

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE IOT_AVRO_DATA
(mycolumn VARIANT);

copy INTO IOT_AVRO_DATA
FROM @GOOGLE_BUCKET_SFHOL/iot_files/iot_files_sample_output.avro;
FILE_FORMAT = (type = AVRO);

It looks like there is a mismatch between the number of columns in the file and in the table.

Any help advice would be appreciated, tried reaching out to snowflake via the workshop but they have not responded.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your AVRO file is not corrupted?

The following works fine for me:

Upload to my stage a sample avro file (userdata1.avro taken from [here](https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/tree/master/samples/sample-data/avro))

```
spanaite#(no warehouse)@SERGIU_DB.(no schema)>put file:///Users/spanaite/Downloads/userdata1.avro @~;
+----------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------+
| source         | target            | source_size | target_size | source_compression | target_compression | status   | message |
|----------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------|
| userdata1.avro | userdata1.avro.gz |       93561 |       79248 | NONE               | GZIP               | UPLOADED |         |
+----------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 3.026s
spanaite#(no warehouse)@SERGIU_DB.(no schema)>
```

Create a table and load the avro file:

```
create or replace table test_avro(mycolumn VARIANT);
copy into test_avro from @~/userdata1.avro.gz file_format = (type = AVRO);
select * from test_avro;
```

Try with one of the sample files from the link I posted above.

Comment: Thank you, yes the file from your link worked fine so it looks like the file from the snowflake course is corrupted